# Getting 403 when fetching Venues

Tags: android, location, here-api

I used "https://developer.here.com/documentation/venue-maps/topics/resource-type-venues-index.html" to get venues I have created using the "Here Indoor Radio Mapper", but I am getting 403 error.

I can see the venues I have created in "Here Indoor Radio Mapper" and I have published it. I requested signature information from -"https://developer.here.com/documentation/venue-maps/topics/request-signature.html" and used it in the above url with my appid and appcode but I am still getting 403 when I hit the url. I have used the same email address in the "Here Indoor Radio Mapper" and the one I used to create sdk credential. I used Android SDK premium

> E/Volley: [3001] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for
>
> http://static-3.venue.maps.api.here.com/1/model-poi/index_bb.json?Policy={Policy_id}
>       &Signature={signature}&Key-Pair-Id={keyPair}&app_id={appId}&app_code={appCode}

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Error codes and their meaning. So as per your response code it seems like app_id and app_code is incorrect.

[image: Error Code]

Hope this helps.!